# Dotcloud Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal - ramen

Tags: dotcloud

I recently tried to push one of the php examples on dotcloud and I got the error below. I am not sure how to get it to allocate the pseudo-terminal...

```
dotcloud push ramen ramen-on-dotcloud   
# upload ramen-on-dotcloud ssh://dotcloud@uploader.dotcloud.com:443/ramen   
# rsync  
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.  
building file list ... done  

sent 141 bytes  received 20 bytes  35.78 bytes/sec  
total size is 55  speedup is 0.34  
22:34:16 ---> Deploy of "ramen" scheduled for revision rsync-1339454056336 at 2012-06-11  
              22:34:16  
22:34:17 ---> Building the application...  
22:34:17 [www] Build started for revision rsync-1339454056336 (clean build)  
22:34:18 [www] I am snapshotsworker_00/bob-2, and I will be your builder today.  
22:34:21 [www] Build completed successfully. Compiled image size is 427KB  
22:34:21 ---> Application build is done  
22:34:21 ---> Initializing new services... (This may take a few minutes)  
22:34:21 ---> Using default scaling for service www (1 instance(s)).  
22:34:21 ---> No new services found  
22:34:21 ---> All services have been initialized. Deploying code...  
22:34:21 [www.0] Deploying build revision rsync-1339454056336...  
22:34:25 [www.0] Running postinstall script...  
22:34:27 [www.0] Launching...  
22:34:28 [www.0] Waiting for the instance to become responsive...  
22:34:28 [www.0] Re-routing traffic to the new build...
22:34:29 [www.0] Successfully deployed build revision rsync-1339454056336  
22:34:29 ---> Deploy finished  
22:34:29 ---> Application fully deployed  

Deployment finished. Your application is available at the following URLs
www: http://ramen-l.dotcloud.com/
```

Comment: what error are you referring too? I don't see an error listed in the output you provided. The "Pseudo-terminal" line is a normal one, and isn't an error. If you notice the last line that says "Application fully deployed" that means it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-terminal message is informative. It does not indicate an error in this case.
Note that at the bottim it indicates

> 22:34:29 ---> Deploy finished
>   22:34:29 ---> Application fully deployed
>   Deployment finished. Your application is available at the following
>   URLs www: http://ramen-l.dotcloud.com/

so everything went fine.

/A